# How can I fix mitmproxy is not showing app traffic

Tags: android, mitmproxy

I have set up mitmproxy on Ubuntu, and have linked my android device to it. I can view traffic coming from the android browser but when I launch an app, it does not show me any traffic from the app (any app it seems), even though the app is connecting to the internet. What am I doing wrong?

The mitmproxy command I am running is `~mitmproxy --host`

Answer (score 0):

This is probably because of SSL pinning read about it here or it could be that the app is ignoring the Android proxy settings, but most likely SSL pinning from my experience

http://docs.mitmproxy.org/en/stable/certinstall.html#certificate-pinning